# How to add values or add object into NSArray in Objective C using for loop?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsarray, nsdictionary

Well this is my code:

```
NSDictionary *dicto;
NSString *ndccode;
NSString *string=@" ";
for (int i=0; i<array.count; i++) {
    dicto=[array objectAtIndex:i];
    ndccode=[dicto objectForKey:@"NDCCode"];
    string=[string stringByAppendingString:ndccode];
   string=[string stringByAppendingString:@"\n"];
    NSLog(@"%@",string);
}
NSLog(@"%@",string);
```

In the above code, i have values in dicto nsdictionary which loops one by one value and assigns to ndccode which is string. Then I am adding to string so that I can append it to the next line.

output :
name1 
name2 
name3
.....

Instead of assigning to the string. I want to assign it to an array.Could you please tell me how to assign it to an array for this example,since it is in loop. I want to use the array for later purposes.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: NSMutableArray *resultArray = [NSMutableArray array]; in your loop, [resultArray addObject:string];

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
NSDictionary *dicto;
NSString *ndccode;
NSMutableArray *outputArray=[NSMutableArray new];
for (int i=0; i<array.count; i++) {
    dicto=[array objectAtIndex:i];
    ndccode=[dicto objectForKey:@"NDCCode"];
    [outputArray addObject:ndccode];
}
```

or even more succinctly

```
NSArray *outputArray = [array valueForKey:@"NDCCode"];
```

Comment: Perfect.I appreciate your help.